# Call a Swift function

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

```
let imageOne = images[0] as! UIImage
let imageTwo = images[1] as! UIImage
```

I have a function

```
    func uploadImage(image: UIImage){
                                        let randomName = randomStringWithLength(length: 5)
                                        let randomNames = randomStringWithLength(length: 9)
                                        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOne, 1.0)
                                        let imageDatas = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageTwo, 1.0)
                                        let uploadRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(randomName).jpg")


                                        let uploadTask = uploadRef.put(imageData!, metadata: nil) { metadata,
                                            error in
                                            if error == nil {
                                                print("successfully uploaded Image")
                                                AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
                                                self.imageFileName = "\(randomName as String).jpg"


                                        let uploadTaskTwo = uploadRef.put(imageDatas!, metadata: nil) { metadata,
                                                        error in
                                                        if error == nil {
                                                            self.imageFileNameTwo = "\(randomNames as String).jpg"
                                                        }

                                                let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
                                                    "imageOne" : self.imageFileName,
                                                    "imageTwo" : self.imageFileNameTwo,



                                                ]
}}else{
print("Error  uploading image")
}
```

I want to call on the function, with multiple images.

```
    if let pickedImage = ((imageOne as? UIImage) != nil), ((imageTwo as? UIImage) != nil) {
    uploadImage(image: pickedImage)                                          
}
```

But I keep getting the error "initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'. Please help me.

Comment: Please [search on an error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+initializer+for+conditional+binding+must+have+Optional+type%2C+not) before posting. There are many topics covering this already.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using optional binding to check `nil`?

```
 if let variable` = optional var {}
```

The above semantic means if `optional var` will have some value then that will be get assigned to `variable`.

Now coming to your question,

```
  if let pickedImage = ((imageOne as? UIImage) != nil) {
  }
```

In your case, if `imageOne as? UIImage` is not nil then ony it will get assigned to `pickedImage` but this expression`((imageOne as? UIImage) != nil)` is `Bool` type.

If you need to check `nil` value then you should have used just `if`

```
  let pickedImage = imageOne as? UIImage
  if pickedImage != nil {
  }
```

Further, I will suggest reading [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Comment: I apologise, I am very new to swift. The function I know how to use the function when I have one image, my problem is using it when I have multiple images.

Comment: I had `if let pickedImage = imageOne, imageTwo as? UIImage {' and xcode suggested what I have above instead

Comment: use `if let pickeImageFirst = imageOne as? UIImage, pickedImageSecond = imageTwo as? UIImage { // if they are not nil then you can use inside this block } `

Comment: if let pickedImageFirst = imageOne as? UIImage, let pickedImageSecond = imageTwo as? UIImage {uploadImage(image: pickedImageFirst)} @Rahul I am not sure what goes inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
     var test1: String? = "Test1" // in your code imageOne
     var test2: String? = nil // and imageTwo

     if let test = test1 ?? test2 {
         print(test) // Output: "Test1"
     }
```

The nil-coalescing operator a ?? b is a shortcut for

```
     a != nil ? a! : b
```

it returns either the left operand unwrapped or the right operand.

Comment: I don't only want to output test 1, I want to output test 2 as well